# Regex to add spacing between sentences in a string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use a spanish dictionary api that returns definitions with small issues. This specific problem happens when the definition has more than 1 sentence. Sometimes the sentences are not properly separated by a space character, so I receive something like this:

> This is a sentence.Some other sentence.Sometimes there are no spaces between dots. See?

Im looking for a regex that would replace "." for ". " when the dot is immediately followed by a char different than the space character. The preg_replace() should return:

> This is a sentence. Some other sentence. Sometimes there are no spaces between dots. See?

So far I have this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=[a-zA-Z])[.]/','. ',$string);
```

The problem is that it also adds a space when there is already a space after the dot. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\.)\.(?!(\s|$|\,|\w\.))/', '. ', $string);
```

Comment: Any way you could tweak that regex to omit dots that are followed by commas? For example: "in this eg., the character dies." < the "eg.," should not become "eg. ,"

Comment: @andufo: Tweaked! But it's actually e.g., not eg., so you'll need to make exceptions, I suppose. Edit: I tweaked it again to accept things like e.g. and initials.

Comment: thanks again. i'll implement something to avoid the e.g., maybe str replacing the e.g. for plain eg. (since this is for a spanish dictionary, this will work for the etc.,)

Comment: @andufo: Seriously, though, eg. is wrong. The correct spelling is e.g.. And this expression handles it, so don't worry :)

Comment: thanks :) ~ i found another scenario (very possible when it comes on definitions). If the string is: "Some text (some parenthesis).Some other text." it won't work :s

Answer (score 3):

```
echo preg_replace( '/\.([^, ])/', '. $1', $string);
```

[It works!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GycDjP)

Comment: Could you tweak that regex to omit dots that are followed by commas? For example: "in this eg., the character dies." < the "eg.," should not become "eg. ,"

Comment: @andufo - Sure, just place a comma inside the capturing group. I edited my answer and [it appears to work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hd5YTR).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply a look-ahead to so adds a space if the next character is something other than a space or is not the end of the string:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-zA-Z])[.](?![\s$])/','. ',$string);
```

Comment: there should be a comma protection. For example: "in this eg., the character dies." < the "eg.," should not become "eg. ,"

Comment: preg_replace('/(?<=[a-zA-Z])[.](?![\s$,|\,])/','. ',$string)